# Como aplicar o javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero que quando a pessoa clique na opção um e depois clicar na dois, a 1 seja desmarcada.

```
<script>

        function mudaImagem (foto){
            document.getElementById("vamo") .src =foto;
        }
        function selecionaPequeno(){
            document.getElementById("bora") .src = "imagens/P1.gif";
        }
        function voltaPequeno(){
            document.getElementById("bora") .src = "imagens/P1.png";
        }
        function selecionaMedio(){
            document.getElementById("corre") .src = "imagens/P1.gif";
        }
        function selecionaGrande(){
            document.getElementById("neh") .src = "imagens/G3.png";
        }
        function selecionaGigantesco(){
            document.getElementById("jeh") .src = "imagens/GG3.png";
        }


</script>
```

HTML

```
<img src="imagens/P1.png" id="bora" name="opa" onclick="selecionaPequeno()" width="56" height="35" />
<img src="imagens/P1.png" id="corre" name="opa" onclick="selecionaMedio()" width="56" height="35" />
```

Comment: Está faltando detalhes na sua pergunta, desmarcado o que? Ponha o código completo ou uma boa parte para entendermos o que precisas.

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML dessas opções?

Answer (score 0):

A explicação não ficou clara mas acredito que a ideia seja essa:

**HTML**

```
<img id="bora" name="opa" src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/577/PNG/256/ExecutiveCar_Black_icon-icons.com_54904.png"/>
<img id="corre" name="opa"src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/127817/isolated/lists/4fd0c9dcae60a9a63579b9b6853eeb09-carro-de-besouro-retro-brilhante.png" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bora").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $("#corre").removeClass("selected");
  });
  $("#corre").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      $("#bora").removeClass("selected");
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.selected { border: 2px dashed red; }
```

RESULTADO

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigorf/3mqp75oa/